# How to get the version of tensorflow object detection API

Tags: tensorflow

I have used Tensorflow object detection API. Recently I upgrade my Tensorflow version and some incompatibility issues happen. for this reason I need to know my Tensorflow object detection API version to know the compatible version of Tensorflow to install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Please report the commit SHA of the tensorflow/models git repo (you can find this by running `git log`).

Comment: Since I got files directly from GitHab web (without using the `git clone`) it complain `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`